# Get combined checksum of first n rows in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I want to get a checksum of supposing the first 100 rows combined checksum.

Saw this [mysql-rows-checksum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35196807/mysql-rows-checksum), but this gives a checksum for every row. I want only one checksum for given n rows combined.

Comment: "I want only one checksum for given n rows combined" -- Why? Perhaps you can get the checksums of your first N rows and concatenate them?

Comment: What OS?  I can imagine an easy way to pipe a SELECT to some other checksum utility.

Comment: @RickJames on Mysql there is a command like `checksum table <tablename>`. So any feasibility something like `checksum table <table_name> <rows_count>`

Comment: @mustaccio say for example, if I try to get checksum of first 1000 rows everytime. Wouldn't it be messier to concatenate them and have a large string. If you got any idea to get a simplified checksum help me out.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CHECKSUM(CONCAT(column1, column2, column3, ...)) AS combined_checksum
FROM your_table
ORDER BY primary_key_column
LIMIT n;
```